# What technology does smart keys for car use?

Tags: sensor, rf, rfid

How does a smart key know that the driver is in the car?

Comment: From own experience, I can tell you, it doesn't.

Comment: Because it is smart!

Comment: It is done by magic :-) Probably your car has a sensor in the driver's seat which detects if you're sitting on it or not.

Answer (score 2):

The smart key doesn't sense the driver.

The car senses the smart key.

Comment: Destructive answer!

Answer (score 2):

There are sensors around the car, and inside the car that probe the key with a 125 kHz signal. Based on how many sensors pick up the response from the key and the strengths of these responses, the car can locate the key with enough precision.